# `gulp.watch` blocking execution of `dotnet run`

Tags: c#, npm, gulp, .net-core

I'm executing `gulp.watch` as part of a precompile script in a .NET Core project. When executing `dotnet run` the `gulp.watch` call seems to block the thread, so that the application won't start at all.

How can I tell `gulp.watch` to return the handle to the thread?

I have created a minimum working example to reproduce the problem using `dotnet new` and installing `gulp` via `npm`.

This is my `gulpfile.js`:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('copy', () => {
    gulp.src("watch_src/foo.txt")
      .pipe(gulp.dest("watch_dst/"));
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    var watcher = gulp.watch("watch_src/foo.txt", ['copy']);
    watcher.on('change', function(){
        console.log('foo.txt changed!');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

My `Program.cs` file looks like:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

My `project.json` file looks like:

```js
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precompile": "gulp"
  }
}
```

Executing `dotnet run` will execute the precompile script and changes to `foo.txt` are reflected by the event handler on the console. But the `Main` method that should print `Hello World!` does not get executed:

```bsh
c:\Temp\src\gulptest>dotnet run
Compiling gulptest for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
[17:03:48] Using gulpfile c:\Temp\src\gulptest\gulpfile.js
[17:03:48] Starting 'watch'...
[17:03:48] Finished 'watch' after 11 ms
[17:03:48] Starting 'default'...
[17:03:48] Finished 'default' after 43 ╬╝s
foo.txt changed!
[17:04:15] Starting 'copy'...
[17:04:15] Finished 'copy' after 34 ms
```

Comment: I've also tried to use the `gulp-watch` plugin, but it behaves the same.

Comment: did you finally find the answer? I would be interested to know it. Thanks

Comment: No. Unfortunately it seems that either no one else has this problem or that they solved it in another way. I have also tried to get in contact with the gulp community [here](https://gitter.im/gulpjs/gulp) but no luck.

Comment: Damn I was hopping you give me the answer. I really want this. I just posted a [tweet](https://twitter.com/Koenigsbier/status/788240740258164736). If you have an account, please RT. Hope the community will see it...

Answer (score 1):

I am using vs code and I've met the question as you too

In the **`project.json`**,you have the section:

```
"scripts": {
    "precompile": "gulp"
  }
```

which will stuck the **`dotnet run`**

Following these steps If you want to launch **`dotnet run`** and **`gulp watch`**

Step1: Define a new task in **`task.json`** file:

```
 {
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gulp watch",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "gulp-watch"
 }
```

Step2: Add a new launch  configuration in **`launch.json`**:

```
  {

            "name": "gulp-watch",
            "preLaunchTask": "gulp-watch",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node"
  },
```

Step3: Add compound configuration in the **`launch.json`**:

```
 "compounds": [{
        "name": ".Net+gulp",
        "configurations": [
            "gulp-watch",
            ".NET Core Launch (web)"
        ]
    }],
```

For more detail,please refer to this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 0):

The main method in ASP.NET core should look like -

```
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
```

The one you are showing above is pure console application and gulp is not required for it.